# upload_err_no_file ошибка 4

Tags: php, apache, nginx

Есть у меня сайт на виртуальном хостинге. Так вот недавно из за ддос атак попросил у ребят с тех. обслуживания помочь предотвратить. Теперь не могу на сайте аплодить фотографии. Веб сервер на apache с прокси сервером nginx. С правами все в порядке. К тому же обновил PHP и Apache. Гуглил, ответа так и не нашёл.

Comment: А к ребятам с тех. обслуживания обращались повторно или нет?

Comment: Что значит не можете аплоадить? Какие ошибки, на каком этапе не работает, как загружаете?

Comment: Это новостной сайт. Есть cms часть сайта, там загружаются новости. Новость заливается, а вот фотографии нет. Стоит flash(swfupload) и html5 загрузки. При флеше выдает ошибку -220, что значит IO Error, на HTML5 upload_err_no_file(error 4).Уже две недели ничего найти не могу.